# Wayland: Install a GNOME 3 Desktop (pilfs)

Tags: wayland, weston

I have built [PiLFS](http://intestinate.com/pilfs) on my Raspberry Pi 2. I have also build Wayland/Weston on it. But, I want to install a GNOME 3.20.x desktop on it. How would I do so?